# How to figure out if onto and $1-1$ for two cases.

Tags: functions

I have to figure out if the function is $1-1$ and onto but I'm not sure how to do it if I have $2$ cases.

$\mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$, where $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is the set of all positive integers.
$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
2x & \mbox{if $x$ is odd}\\
x - 1 & \mbox{if $x$ is even}
\end{cases} 
$$

From trying it out is seems to not be onto, because if you plug in even integers you won't hit 4.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers (whether positive, negative or zero)

Comment: In the problem it has Z^+ which wasn't working when I tried to type it in.

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the function is 1-1 because it maps odd integers 1-1 to even integers, and it maps even integers 1-1 to odd integers. For onto, you are correct, there is no way to ever get a number divisible by $4$. You can show this for example by computing the remainder of the function value when you divide by $4$ for both cases of the function.

Comment: OK so that would I think helps me with my other problem which is Z→N(set of all non-negative integers). f(n) = -2n n≤0 and f(n)= n > 0. So it would be 1-1 because n≤0 maps even and n > 0 maps odd. And it would be onto because it covers ever integer. Although it doesnt drop negative, but N is all non-negative integers.

Comment: n>0 does not map to odd. Consider f(2).

Comment: Sorry misstyped. f(n)=-2n when n≤0. f(n) = 2n-1 when n>0.